# Confusion on one-sided mannwhitney test parameters (alternative hypothesis)

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, statistical-significance, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm trying to figure out what the default alternative hypothesis of this test means.

**If my significance threshold is 0.05, is it incorrect to say only p-values < 0.05 are significant or are values > 0.95 also significant?**

I just want to say the distribution of vector `u` is significantly different than vector `v` regardless of the direction (if this makes sense).

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html[image]

Comment: A p-value > 0.95 is not significant.  The two-sided nature of the test is taken into account by the "alternative" parameter, so that you just need to worry about a single 0.05 threshold. ... Also, the hypothesis for the Mann Whitney test in the question isn't stated quite correctly.

Comment: mostly duplicated here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259112/interpretation-of-p-value-in-mann-whitney-rank-test

Comment: While the link covers most of the question (which is why I initially closed as duplicate), I've reopened as the last aspect of the question isn't dealt with there. I'd suggest editing to focus more explicitly just on that aspect if possible